# While debugging, the error "Unable to perform this action because the process is running." comes out

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, remote-debugging, vscode-debugger

I debug the c program using vscode connecting Ubuntu remotely.here is some screenshots below.
[this error will appear after I start the debugging and step in for several times,the most interesting is that the number of steps is uncertain,sometimes the error will appear after three steps,sometimes it's four,five or more.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0gkxU.png)

I have searched the problem on net,some people have the same error but the different reason with me,so I really have no ideas about it.help me,please!I'd very appreciate.
[I also find the same error in here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdggX.png)
By the way,changing the "externalConsole"from false to true doesn't work,the debugger will be stuck forever,like this below.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QLedh.png)
But I still speculate it's related to "externalConsole" in launch.json.

Today is after two days of finding the error,I used vscode on ubuntu directly not remotely to debug the program.And I turned the externalconsole true,but the error appeared again.

> [image: Blockquote]

Today is June 12,it's been a long time,and I still haven't solved this problem,I feel disappointed and a little numb. If someone can solve my problem,I will give him money!
During these days,I uninstalled vscode and installed it again.Then I use it with offical documents and codes,and this error occurs again,so I speculate maybe the app vscode itself has some problems.